# Coldfusion Ajax-Request throws JSON.parse error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, coldfusion

I have a pretty simple Ajax-Request. It just requests some data from a database. The problem is that I'm always getting an JSON.parse error (first row, first column). The JSON the Coldfusion function outputs is valid and correct.

When I just copy the code to a .cfc file everything works just fine. Why is that?

Coldfusion:

```
<cffunction name="getAllDatatypes" access="remote" returntype="query" returnformat="json">

    <cfquery name="getAllDatatypes" datasource="#DSN#">
        SELECT
            id_datatype,
            name
        FROM
            datatype
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn getAllDatatypes>

</cffunction>
```

JQuery:

```
function getAllDatatypes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getData.cfm",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {method: "getAllDatatypes"}       
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).fail(function(error1, error2, error3) {
        console.log(error1 + " " + error2 + " " + error3);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `remote` function in a `.cfc` file, the CFC path starts to act like a webservice would. When you make the call like following,

`http://localhost/components/testcomp.cfc?method=getAllDatatypes`

ColdFusion knows that you are trying to invoke a remote function `getAllDatatypes` in the `components/testcomp.cfc` component and it is invoked if remote function `getAllDatatypes` is found and the response is returned as either `plaintext`, `xml` or `json`.

On the other hand. Any calls to a `.cfm` file, there is not such scenario. Even if you have created a function in the file, ColdFusion is not looking to a remote method call into a `.cfm` file.

PS: It is always a good idea to initialize variables in side a function using `var` or use `local` scope.

Comment: @JenSeReal - Also, for greater flexibility, consider specifying `returnformat="json"` in the URL instead of hard coding it in the function.